# How to convert the given string into an array?

Tags: python, string

I have an array represented as a string.

**Example:** 
'[20,543,564,1234,67]'

How to convert this string into an array of integers in python3 as follows:-

[20,543,564,1234,67]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [75]: import ast                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [76]: s = '[20,543,564,1234,67]'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [77]: ast.literal_eval(s)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[77]: [20, 543, 564, 1234, 67]
```